# JQuery slider, strange performance after tab change

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I've created a slider with JQuery but now a strange performance appear after a tab change in Firefox and Chrome.

If you change the tab and go back there are more boxes opens or the slider change fast and without any logic... or many many other strange things.

So I realy dont know what's the problem of firefox and chrome :D

Can someone help me or someone has ANY idea why this happens?

Comment: This could be related to the requestAnimationFrame stuff that was [reverted](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/08/29/jquery-1-6-3-rc1-released/) in the latest version of jQuery. Try with the [newest version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js).

Comment: I also find this solution, but "We’ve removed support for this API (which has no impact on the way you call jQuery’s animation features) and plan to incorporate it into a future version of jQuery."....badluck for me :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok Guys I've found the Answer to this question after a while:

In JQuery 1.6.2 they implemented the new "requestAnimationFrame". But this donsnt work very well at the moment and produce the "[animation worm holes](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/)" like I describe in my question here!

In JQuery 1.6.3 they removed this API and now it works fine again ;)

Here is the Bug-Ticket: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9381

Kind Regards 
Raphael

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is that the different animations are not in sync.
**You should work on making subsequent animations as callbacks!**
JavaScript does not have a SLEEP thing to it. As soon as it gets a call for a function, it tries to execute it.
But when you are away from a window/tab, the browser takes away much of the processing powers from the inactive tab to provide better power to the new current tab.
Although, a stack of the functions called on the inactive tab is maintained and as soon as the tab regains the processing power, the stack is emptied as soon as possible.
(this is the reason that the page comes back to normal functionality in a few seconds)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "You should work on making subsequent animations as callbacks!" give me an example! would be nice :) Or better show me that in my fiddle

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that while you're not focused on the window, the rolling animation of the image does not occur. They all occurs when you're getting the focus back.

Adding stop in the rotate call seems to help.

```
$(".image_roll").stop(true, true).animate({
    left: -image_rollPosition
}, 1200, 'easeInOutQuart');
```

However I'm not very familiar with all the animate / stop functions of jQuery, so there might be some other stuff to change. (It seems that the change I indicated is doing a little bug when the focus goes back on the window, but imho it's still better than before).

See http://jsfiddle.net/fc7Xc/104/ for the example.

Comment: I've tested this, but in my Browsers FF 5+6 and Chrome 10.x this fix dosn't change anything... mhm

Comment: That's weird, it works for me in ff 7 and chrome 13. The two first slides are a bit weird (the different tab have a problem in size), but after that everything is Ok.